# SharePoint: Site Layouts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Hi I was wondering which Layout I could use to get the search box in the top right hand corner.  I used *(Welcome Page) Blank Web Part Page)* as the page layout but its missing the search box in the top right corner.

Also another question:  How can I add my own layouts to the list in the Create Page, page.  Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the search box in the upper right by default?
As for your other question, do you mean Create Site?

Comment: Yeah, search box is defined in the master page.

Comment: Nat, the placement of the search box can be defined in the MasterPage. However, the actual search box used is defined as part of the Site Template right?

Comment: aagh, it's all so complicated. I have coded search boxes into the masterpage, but maybe you do have to override a placeholder in others.

Answer (score 1):

The search box is defined in your master page.  Ususally default.master, it would not matter which layout you choose the elements defined in the master page will still be in the same place.  In your case it would appear that the search box does not exist on your master and would need to be added in again.

You would need to amend the master page for your site and add the appropriate SP control for search into the appropriate place on your page.  This will ensure that a SP search box is rendered in that location for every page.

Answer (score 0):

To define your own page layout have a look at [Link 1](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101741281033.aspx) and [Link 2](http://www.wssdemo.com/Blog/archive/2008/10/27/creating-a-sharepoint-page-layout-to-play-video-content.aspx).

As for the search box, it is defined as part of the Site Template. Try creating a Site using the Collaboration Site template.